# Why does matrix exponentiation work with transposes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A^T$ denote the transpose of $A$.

Is it true that $(A^n)^T = (A^T)^n$?

Comment: Because $(A\cdot A)^t = A^t \cdot A ^t$ - and induction. Also, you're missing a bracked. It's not $t^n$, but $(A^t)^n$

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous. Right now it looks like $t$ is just some number, not an indication of the transpose. Also, conventionally, the transpose is denoted with a capital $T$. So are you asking if the transpose of a power is the power of the transpose? That is, are you asking if $(A^n)^T = (A^T)^n$?

Comment: Yes @Xoque55 that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

The answer is affirmative. Maybe generalizing the properties of matrix transposes and powers will be insightful.

Let $A_i$ be a square matrix for $i=1,2,3,...,n$.

Consider the matrix product $B = A_1 A_2 A_3 \cdots A_n$. Recall that $(XY)^T = Y^T X^T$. It can be shown by induction that $$B^T = (A_1 A_2 A_3 \cdots A_n)^T \\
= A_n^T \cdots A_3^T A_2^T A_1^T.$$

In the special case where $A_i = A$ for all $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$, then we have $B = AAA\cdots A = A^n$. Similarly, we have $B^T = A^T \cdots A^T A^T A^T = (A^T)^n$. But since $B = A^n$, then $B^T = (A^n)^T$. So altogether, we have $(A^n)^T = (A^T)^n$. QED

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it follows from the fact $(AB)^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}$. Here let $B=A$.